# How to restore shortcuts to Anaconda after upgrading to Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, anaconda

Recently I upgraded from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10. Although Windows said it didn't change anything to my files and folders, this was not the case. Only one of the shortcuts in my Anaconda folder in the start menu remained. This was the Anaconda Prompt so I thought I just run the following commands to fix my links:

```
conda update conda -f
conda update anaconda -f
```

Although this returned a few links, it did not restore everything which means I was stuck with a dysfunctional installation of Anaconda.

Answer (score 25):

The following worked for me (albeit on Windows 7):

- Open a command prompt as administrator
- Execute `"C:\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe" "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\_nsis.py" mkmenus`

Comment: I had this problem after updating to Windows 10 Anniversary Update. I had to use this command (edit username): `"C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe" "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\Lib\_nsis.py" mkmenus`

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I use Miniconda. When I updated with

```
conda update conda
```

there were these following lines along with the list of packages to be updated:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
console_shorcut-0.1.1-3
powershell_shortcut-0.0.1-2
```

I saw those lines after the update and the shortcut to the command window was gone. So I restored the Anaconda Prompt command window shortcut with

`conda install console_shortcut`

Comment: i tried `conda install console_shortcut` with Anaconda3 on Windows 10, and it worked

Answer (score 4):

`mkmenus` did not work for me but the following worked on Windows 10 32-bit, Miniconda3.

1. Open command prompt (admin privileges not required).
2. Navigate to your Miniconda\Scripts directory. Replace `kk` with your username.

   ```
   cd "C:\Users\kk\Miniconda3\Scripts"
   ```
3. Run Activate.bat

   ```
   activate.bat
   ```
4. Install console_shortcut.

   ```
   conda install -c anaconda console_shortcut
   ```

Comment: Wow, this worked for me! Thank you. Since I installed anaconda for all users in the computer my anaconda scripts were found in the following path: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts

Answer (score 3):

When using Miniconda installed for the local user:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\pythonw.exe C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\Lib\_nsis.py mkmenus
```

This was also on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I did the following:

1. Remove Anaconda with "add or remove program" [link](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install#windows-uninstall)
2. Reinstall Anaconda with the latest installer [link](https://www.continuum.io/downloads#_windows)

After this everything is restored and since the uninstall program [does not remove user files](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/faq#what-causes-files-left-behind-after-uninstalling-anaconda-on-windows) your environments and settings are also still there. If for some reason you stored projects in the Anaconda folder, this folder will be removed so watch out for that ;)