# How can I expose/launch Anaconda on Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I just downloaded and installed Anaconda, for Windows, from here.

https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/windows/

I just followed the prompts and everything seemed to have installed normally, and I see the directory and all folders and files here.

C:\Users\my_path\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3

However, when I click the Start button I don't see Anaconda installed as a shortcut and when I search for it (next to the Start button) I don't see anything related to Anaconda.  Is there an easy way to create shortcuts for Anaconda, Spyder, the command prompt, etc?  Thanks.

Comment: Possible answer from [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35580171/243245): `pythonw _nsis.py mkmenus` from your anacoda3\lib folder.

Answer (score -1):

First, go that .exe location of Anaconda navigator. Then right click --> send to desktop. Now you have a shortcut on the desktop. Now on the desktop, right click on the shortcut and you will see 'pin to start'.

Comment: No, no, that's the whole problem.  I don't have Anaconda Navigator showing up so I can't pin it to the Start button.  Also, I tried the following: "C:\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe" "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\_nsis.py" mkmenus

It ran in the standard Windows Command Prompt just fine (running as Administrator); no errors.  It didn't actually do anything though.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, except I don't have a file named anaconda-navigator.exe.  I am missing this as well as Spyder, the Anaconda Command Prompt, etc., etc.  I have a bunch of files and folder in the this path: 'C:\Users\my_path\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3'.  That's it.  I uninstalled and re-installed everything; getting the same results now.  I have Visual Studio installed, and all related packages for that framework.  Maybe that's the problem.  I doubt it though.  I have installed Anaconda many times on other computers and I have never seen this issue.  Any other ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Which are the files and folder on the path `C:\Users\my_path\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3`? Possible that your installation is not right (installing from the incorrect installer). Which version you downloaded and the URL or it? I don't think that Visual Studio will cause any problem otherwise it would have thrown an error.

Comment: I'm in the directory where Anaconda is installed.  I see no file called AnacondaNavigator.exe.  There's a file called _conda.exe.  There's a subdirectory called "pkgs" that has anaconda-navigator.exe.  There's also a anaconda-navigator.exe in the Scripts subdirectory.  There's also anaconda.exe under anaconda-client.  Which one am I supposed to use?

Comment: Hmm, when I reinstalled Anaconda to run non-privileged from my user directory, this was the value for "properties" for Anaconda Navigator in my start menu:
C:\Users\myusername\anaconda3\pythonw.exe C:\Users\myusername\anaconda3\cwp.py C:\Users\myusername\anaconda3 C:\Users\myusername\anaconda3\pythonw.exe C:\Users\myusername\anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py